# How do I make a new directory and write a new 'wb' file in python?

Tags: python, directory, writefile

I have this part of the function that won't seem to work properly. It says the directory does not exist, but I am trying to save it under a new one. I just don't know what I am doing wrong. I know how to make directories and files (I thought).

```
import os
from datetime import date

def save_image(d, image):
    """
    Save binary image on disk.

    Use the date of the image (d) to create a directory structure 
    (year/month) if it doesn't exist already,
    then save the binary image under its corresponding year and month using 
    the date (d) + '.jpg' as a file name

    HINT: Binary data can be written to files in a similar way to how 
    strings are written to files.
    Use 'wb' (write binary) instead of 'w' in the file open clause (i.e. 
    open(file_path, 'wb'))

    args:
        d: date object containing image date
        image: binary image itself

    returns:
        file_path: where the image was saved

    examples:
        if d = 2017-8-21, the image will be saved as: 2017/8/2017-8-21.jpg
        if d = 1998-4-15, the image will be saved as: 1998/4/1998-4-15.jpg
    """

    ds = str(d.year)+'/'+str(d.month)
    file_path = ds+'/'+str(d)+'.jpg'
```

up to this point the file_path is written similar to the example, but after this it won't make the new directory. It just gives an error saying directory does not exist. I am so confused why it won't let me make a new directory and then save the image under the new file. ANY IDEAS?

```
    os.mkdir(ds)
    with open(file_path, 'wb') as file:
        file.write(image)
    return file_path
```

Comment: Please show the value of `d` so we can be sure it doesn't contain invalid characters

Comment: it is a date(year, month, day)

Comment: it comes from user input from another function. and I have checked it, the return is what I expected.

Comment: Recommendation: when creating file paths, either use `os.path.join` or the `/` operator with `Path`s from `pathlib` (3.4+).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ds = str(d.year)+'/'+str(d.month)
--> 2018/10
```

That is not a valid directory. 
That are actually two directories.

Use `os.makedirs` to recursively create them.

Comment: Thank you! when I made 2 directories doing it this way it worked perfectly! Now I know in the future.